# Анонимные поля структур, грамматика Go

Tags: golang, struct

[Разбираюсь](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types) с деталями реализации Go.

- Набрёл на такую вещь как анонимные поля структуры. Подскажите, в каким случаях они используются? Я не вижу области применения.

  ```
  // A struct with four anonymous fields of type T1, *T2, P.T3 and *P.T4
  struct  {
      T1        // field name is T1
      *T2       // field name is T2
      P.T3      // field name is T3
      *P.T4     // field name is T4
      x, y int  // field names are x and y
  }
  ```
- Что обозначают вот эти строчки, которые, в контексте, можно увидеть по ссылке выше:

  ```
  StructType     = "struct" "{" { FieldDecl ";" } "}" .
  FieldDecl      = (IdentifierList Type | AnonymousField) [ Tag ] .
  AnonymousField = [ "*" ] TypeName .
  Tag            = string_lit .
  ```

  Правильно ли я понимаю, что данные строки имеют отношение к граматикам, которые использует компилятор? Для чего эта информаия прописана в документации?
- Я также не понимаю, зачем в структуре объявлять поле вида `_`. Как его можно использовать?

  ```
  // A struct with 6 fields.
  struct {
      x, y int
      u float32
      _ float32  // padding
      A *[]int
      F func()
  }
  ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Подскажите, в каким случаях они используются? Я не вижу области применения.

Это один из способов реализации [композиции](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) в Go. Пример:

```
type commonWidget struct {
    width, height int
}

func (w *commonWidget) setHeight(height int) { w.height = height }
func (w *commonWidget) setWidth(width int)   { w.width = width }

type button struct {
    commonWidget
    text string
}

type input struct {
    commonWidget
    type_ string
}
```

Здесь тип `commonWidget` описывает общие для всех виджетов поля и методы. Путём включения, типы `button` и `input` получают как нужные поля, так и методы, с ними работающие.

> Что обозначают вот эти строчки, которые, в контексте, можно увидеть по ссылке выше. Правильно ли я понимаю, что данные строки имеют отношение к граматикам, которые использует компилятор? Для чего эта информаия прописана в документации?

Да, это формальное описание грамматики. Прописана потому что это не просто документация, а *формальная спецификация* языка. По сути, стандарт. Go с самого начала разрабатывался как спецификация, по которой делались два разных компилятора, gc и gccgo. Благодаря тому, что есть спецификация, когда два этих компилятора чем-то различаются, можно понять, кто "не прав". В свою очередь, различия в имплементации компиляторов часто указывают на неполноту спецификации.

> Я также не понимаю, зачем в структуре объявлять поле вида `_`. Как его можно использовать?

Например, чтобы "растянуть" структуру до нужного размера, например чтобы передать её в код на Си, который ожидает структуру определённого размера. Либо чтобы сделать [смещение](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) более заметным.