# Дополнительные значение в структурах Go

Tags: golang

```
type categories struct {
    Id    bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id"` // Зачем это в обратных кавычка?, как влияет на результат?
    Name  string        `bson:"name"`
    Path  string        `bson:"path"`
    About string        `bson:"about"`
    Imgs  string        `bson:"imgs"`
}
```

Работаю с драйвером для mongoDB. использую эти пакеты `github.com/globalsign/mgo` и `"github.com/globalsign/mgo/bson"`

Структуру делал по мануалу, не понимаю, что за значение в обратных кавычках, и как они влияют на результат. Например, если удалять все значения кроме `bson:"_id"` результат не изменится, но если удалить и его работать корректно уже не будет. Плз разъесните, мне google особо не помог.
и Что это за значения такие в структуре? В Туре по го их нет :D

Comment: Пишется "кавычка", а не ковычка

Comment: Погуглите tags golang

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/709873/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-go

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Анонимные поля структур, грамматика Go](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/709873/%d0%90%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80-%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0-go)

Comment: на инлиш но просто отлчиный ответ: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30889373. Если нужен перевод смогу честно плагиировать.